# OCSP Stapling on LAMP with Let's Encrypt

Tags: lamp, ocsp

How do I verify if OCSP Stapling works correctly?

Setup: LAMP with Let's Encrypt, test domain https://pavelstriz.cz/

[High-Tech Bridge result says OCSP is enabled](https://www.htbridge.com/ssl/?id=2cd65be2720735fdecb2903b3761381e5a3ffb1f866e8565ca608eabc102325c)

Is this enough for me to believe the OCSP is set up correctly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a short shell snippet that utilizes openssl:

```
openssl s_client -connect pavelstriz.cz:443 -tls1  -tlsextdebug  -status |grep OCSP -A 2 -B 1
```

You should see something along:

```
OCSP Response Status: successful (0x0)
```